# Virtual functions cannot be friends

Tags: c++

I wish to create an interface for a class C which has this function:

```
friend bool operator==(const C& a, const C& b);*
```

I wish to the create a mock for C for test driven purposes.

I tried doing it like this:

```
class IC
{
    virtual friend bool operator==(const IC& a, const IC& b) = 0;
};
```

What should I do?

Comment: Virtual functions can be friends, but free functions cannot be virtual. A friend declaration doesn't declare a member function (unless you are specifying a member of a different class explicitly). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mehrdad a virtual function only exist in the context of a class. How would you declare it as a friend?

Comment: I wish to mock C. So the code I'm testing will take a MockC (with a IC base) instead of C (with the same IC base). I can then monitor the input arguments to operator==, the number of times the function is called, as well as controlling the return value.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Someone took my comment too seriously! ;)  (This question is getting punny... "virtual functions can't be friends", "I wish to mock C", etc... haha.)

Comment: I suspect sooner or later you will fall into the dual dispatch dielmma. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186123/c-overloading-virtual-operator/10187258#

Answer (score 0):

`operator ==` is a binary operator. To make it `virtual`, it must be a class member.

```
class IC
{
    virtual bool operator==(const IC& b) = 0;
};
```

In this case, the first argument to `==` is implicitly `this`.

Your declaration is about a free function, not a class member.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, you should avoid this and rather implement a `compare` function or similar.

Comment: operator== does not play well with polymorphism, it raises all sorts of questions about how to compare concrete instatnces of objects via references to an abstract class

Comment: @Gart not saying it's easy :)

Comment: It's not only not easy, it's almost always not a good idea. If the "compare" functionality needs to be mocked / abstracted it should probably be in a named function. Changing from a conventional free function implementation of `operator==` is too much of a compromise IMHO.

Comment: What do you mean by compare function? operator== is used to test if the iterator has reached end.

Comment: @Baz why does an iterator need virtual functions? Are you planning on deriving from an iterator ?

Comment: No I wish to derive from the iterator's interface class (IMyIterator) in order to create the classes MyIterator and MyInteratorMock. I will then use MyInteratorMock in my unit tests.